# Magento 2.x how to get ui-select selected value

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, knockoutjs

I have place ui-select component and i want to get value in my custom component.  How can i get selected value in custom component ?

[image]

list.js file

[image]

Here is my output.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
requirejs('uiRegistry').get('productDropdown').initialValue;
```